# Galois group of a field

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, definition, proof-explanation

I was reading the following lemma

[image]

However I cannot understand what "Galois group of $F$" means. I usually look at a Galois group of an extension of fields.

**Note**: the previous result says that if $F$ is loclaly finite and quadratically closed and $[F:E]$, then $E$ is still quadraticlaly closed.

**Reference**: Sylow Theory, Formations and Fitting Classes in Locally Finite Groups. By (author): Martyn R Dixon

Comment: I think it means the Galois group of $F$ over its characteristic field $\Bbb F_p$. Although, the proof seems to be correct for the Galois group of $F/E$ for any subfield $E$ (for which the extension is Galois).

Comment: @GregMartin  I also thought that it could be $\mathbb{F}$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$, but the proof, I think, only works for finite Galois extension. Why you say that works also for an arbitrary Galois extension?

Furthermore seems it to be working on even characteristic?

Comment: Ok, I think by Artin's Lemma everything work fine. However, I think it is still not necessary to assume odd characteristic. What do you think?

Comment: Perhaps the "previous result" requires it?

Comment: Nope, the statement of the previous result is exactly as in the note I wrote in the question: in fact in the proof he distinguish the two cases also (even and odd).